# My Logitech USB Headset/Mic suddenly stopped working

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, microphone, logitech-headset

Yesterday I inadvertently yanked the power plug on my USB hub.  My Logitech headset/mic was plugged into this hub, a fact which may or may not be relevant.  Before I yanked the power cord, the headset was working.

Now it isn't.  I've rebooted.  I have plugged the headset into a bunch of different USB ports, not just on the hub bot on my case itself (ports I have verified as being fully functional).  Windows 7 (x64) doesn't seem to recognize that it has been plugged in.

Is it possible my headset died of shock?  I don't see any issues in the device manager.  I guess I could reinstall my audio driver (sound is on-board), but I'm not clear if that could be a potential solution (to be clear, sound is otherwise working as normal on the machine).

Comment: I have asked 3 really obscure questions on this site; unfortunately they haven't been answered but they were shot-in-the-dark stuff.  If I could mark accepted answers I would.  Alas, it's not meant to be.

Comment: I've had a similar experience with a Logitech USB soundcard (that had headphone and mic outputs) - computer had a very hard lockup, rebooted, now won't ever recognize the device. Other computers do recognize it, *have you tried a different PC?*

Comment: Did you only try connecting the headset through the hub?  What happens if you connected it directly?

Comment: I had forgotten this question existed.  @Kruug - I did try that.  My headset wouldn't work on any of the USB ports on my computer, so I got a new one.

Comment: @studiohack I didn't have another computer to try it on at the time, unfortunately.

Comment: I know it's like eight years later, but I happen to have a win7 laptop that I have to use for the near future. The answer from CharlieRB below - power-down solution worked. Tried all variations of uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers before I tried that. Most aggravating part of this was how the device driver had kept saying "this device is working properly" etc, but wouldn't even play a test tone.  Cheers all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The headset wouldn't work on any of my USB ports, so I just replaced it.  Had I access to another computer, I would have tried it there.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I have seen this happen with other USB devices. Some of those cases were solved by de-energizing the system (even when you reboot equipment still has power). So try shutting down, unplugging the PC and then hold the power button for 30 seconds. Plug it back in and power up. Let it boot completely and then plug your headset in.

Comment: Eight years later! I've got a Win7 laptop that I've got to use for work (slated for replacement but...) Anyway - I tried all kinds of uninstalls/reinstalls etc - the headset had stopped working and the system wouldn't use it. It said it was the device and "working properly" .  But after powering down the system and then removing the battery for a few minutes, and then replacing the battery and booting up -  I plugged in the headset and it is working just fine again. (Mic and Sound are both fixed).

Comment: Further details -  Headset is Logitech H390, nothing fancy but exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having an issue with USB items going to sleep after an extended period of time, go into your Device Manager, expand the USB controller listing (should be the last one in your list) and turn off the Power Management settings. Should be worded something like "Allow the computer to turn off device to save power", give or take a word or two that I'm probably forgetting.

Comment: I don't think the OP's problem is that the USB item went to sleep.